# Manual mini-batch generation for PyTorch Geometric

Tags: pytorch, mini-batch, pytorch-geometric

Currently I have pytorch tensors with shape `(batch_size, height, width, channel_size)` and I want to convert it to a mini-batch described [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/batching.html). My current idea is to convert each example from tensor representation to graph representation separately and group them together. I want to do all these without involving file save/load as it will surely hinder the speed (I notice that [Creating “In Memory Datasets”](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_dataset.html#creating-in-memory-datasets) does it this way).

Yet I didn't find any function for the example grouping part. Could anyone please help give a plausible workflow for it, and is there any smarter way for this convertion, from tensor to mini-batch for pytorch-geometric?

Comment: So you would like to convert `(batch_size, height, width, channel_size)` to something like `(nb_mini_batches, mini_batch_size, height, width, channel_size)`?

Comment: @Ivan Not really. The definition of torch_geometric.data.Data (for graph representation of one example) can be seen [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/introduction.html#mini-batches). I currently plan to first convert each example with shape [height, width, channel_size] to such a representation, but any smarter way is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example with the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm experiencing a similar question with you. If I understand your question correctly, your want to commit following transformation

```
Input: Tensor = [#batch,#vertex,#feature]
Output: torch_geometric.data.BatchData = Large tensor
```

My implementation is:

```
x = DataLoader([Data(x,edge_index=edges,num_node=#node) for x in x],batch_size=#batch)
data = next(iter(x))
```